# Excel - Link a drop down menu to affect an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula, vba

Hopefully this is an easy one. Basically I have a list of item numbers as well as a list of their descriptions in the adjacent column, (Call it "Item numbers" from A1 to A20 and "Item Description" from B1 to B20).  So I have created a drop down for the Descriptions in column B and I want it to automatically fill in the correct Item Number in the adjacent cell in column A.  So i have created a separate table with the corresponding Item Numbers and Descriptions next to each other.  Yet, I can't seem to get a proper formula to reference the original A and B columns.  My research said the Index formula could do it, but I'm not sure. Furthermore, I'm open to a more simpler way as well.
Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you using data validation? If so, you can have a macro execute upon selection to fill in based on the case.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could do this with a `VLOOKUP`, but it can only be used to search in the first column (A). So you have to combine `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$20, MATCH(E11, $B$1:$B$20, 0))
```

where E11 is the cell with the dropdown.